# Consume wcf classes on Client

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to understaned somthing about wcf I have created a wcf project after that I have added the folowing classes

```
namespace WcfService1
{
       [DataContract]
       public abstract class Class1 
       {
         string stam;
         bool bstm;
       }
 }
```

And another class

```
namespace WcfService1
{
       [DataContract]
       public class Class2 : Class1
       {

       }
 }
```

And here is my ServiceContract

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
       [OperationContract]
       string GetData(int value);

    }

}
```

I have add web application to the Solution and added service reference to my wcf service
here is some code from the client

```
Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
ServiceReference1.Class2 c = new ServiceReference1.Class2();
```

Now my Question is how can I create instance of class1 and class2 on the client?

My Error msg:
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'Class2' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApplication1.ServiceReference1' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\workspace\ServerSide\WcfService1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs  15  31  WebApplication1

Comment: First of all, you cannot create instances of abstract classes :- class1 and class2. Secondly, what is Service1Client ?

Comment: Do you ever need to use Class1 or Class2 in the WCF service at all? Will any methods return that class type or get passed the class type as a method parameter?

Comment: yes, i would like to create methods that recives objects from class2, and objects from other class that will implement class1

Comment: to do so, i need to create methods that recives object fro, class1, and in the client side in run time those objects will be from class2

Answer (score 0):

Class1 and Class2 are abstract classes, which means you can't create an instance of them. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx

If you want to return objects of type Class1 or Class2, you will have to:

- Remove `abstract` from the class definition
- Implement a WCF service method that returns objects of Class1 or Class2
- Re-generate the reference to the WCF service, which it looks like you have done before to generate `ServiceClient1`

**Edit**: it sounds based on your comments like you just need to add a reference to the project with Class2 in it. This is something that is very important to know how to do when working with visual studio. Here's a link on how to do that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx

Once the reference is added, add a using statement at the top of the file using Class2, like this:
`using WcfService1`

I would recommend if you are not using Class2 in the service as a parameter or return value that you move it into a different project and reference it from both the client and the service.

Comment: first of all thank
second of all, class 2 is not abstract, this is my bad
now, is it possiable to create instance of class2 on my client without Implementing a WCF service method that returns objects of Class2?

Comment: Either Class2 is abstract, or your example code you've posted is incorrect: "public abstract class Class2"

Comment: If you have a service method that either takes in an instance of Class2 as a parameter or returns an instance of it, it should get created in the service reference. If you don't have any methods that use it, then it shouldn't use the [DataContractAttribute] on it. It will then just be a regular class. When you build the project with Class2 in it, you then can reference that from your client and make use of Class2.

Comment: my code example is incorrect, Class2 is not an abstract class but when i am trying to create it on the client i get an error :Error 4 The type or namespace name 'Class2' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApplication1.ServiceReference1' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\workspace\ServerSide\WcfService1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs 15 64 WebApplication1

Comment: If it's incorrect, then please edit your question so it matches your code.

Comment: ok, i have edited my question. i have added the line in which the error has accured, and added the error msg

Comment: After you update your code, make sure you update your service reference.

Comment: I've updated the question with the using statement required after referencing an assembly.